# schtasks command works when run from CMD, but not from VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

I have the following code in VBScript:

```vb
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs

strArgs = "SchTasks /Create /SC MONTHLY /D 8 /TN ""RespaldoBD"" /TR "'C:\Python27\pythonw.exe  %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\RespaldosBD.py'" /ST 16:33"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

This creates a task in the Task Scheduler in Windows.

When running the VBScript the task is not created, but when I run the command in CMD it works:

```
SchTasks /Create /SC MONTHLY /D 8 /TN ""RespaldoBD"" /TR "'C:\Python27\pythonw.exe  %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\RespaldosBD.py'" /ST 16:33
```

I don't understand what happened.

Comment: You can only run SchTasks.exe with admin permissions, like from an elevated command prompt.  You have to go through the UAC consent dialog.  So the most basic reason by your .vbs script doesn't work is because it is not running elevated.

Comment: @HansPassant No, that's not the issue here. `schtasks` works just fine from a user account for user-level tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript strings start and end with a double quote. Any nested double quotes inside the string **MUST** be escaped by doubling them.

You define `strArgs` like this:

```
strArgs = "SchTasks /Create ... /TR "'C:\Python27\pythonw.exe  %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\RespaldosBD.py'" /ST 16:33"
'         ^                         ^^
'         |                         |`- comment begins here
' string begins here         string ends here
```

Basically you run the command

```
SchTasks /Create /SC MONTHLY /D 8 /TN "RespaldoBD" /TR
```

which, of course, fails.

Normally you'd get a syntax error, but the single quotes you use around the nested command turn the rest of the line into a comment, so the statement is syntactically correct, but semantically broken.

Besides, the single quotes shouldn't be there in the first place. They define the entire Python commandline as the program when that should be only the Python executable. The path to the script is supposed to be an argument.

Change this:

```
strArgs = "SchTasks /Create /SC MONTHLY /D 8 /TN ""RespaldoBD"" /TR "'C:\Python27\pythonw.exe  %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\RespaldosBD.py'" /ST 16:33"
```

into this:

```
strArgs = "SchTasks /Create /SC MONTHLY /D 8 /TN ""RespaldoBD"" /TR ""C:\Python27\pythonw.exe %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\RespaldosBD.py"" /ST 16:33"
```

and both the VBScript and your scheduled task will work.